# Document won't compile when I include \listoffigures or \listoftables

Tags: table-of-contents, export

Simple problem to explain... but I have no idea what info to give to solve it. I'll start with some stuff here, but if you ask me for more info I can provide it.

Basically, my document compiles just find, but if I include a `\listoffigures` or `\listoftables`, it has an error.

I'm in an `article` class document.

The end of the error message after trying to export looks like this:

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] 
[2] [3] (./TSWLatexianTemp_000647.toc [4]) [5] (./TSWLatexianTemp_000647.lof
./TSWLatexianTemp_000647.lof:2: Undefined control sequence.
\ttl@savel@figure #1#2->\ifnum \c@lofdepth 
                                           >\z@ \vskip \cftbeforefigskip {\leftskip \cftfigindent \relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip \parindent \cftfigindent \relax \@afterindenttrue \interlinepenalty \@M \leavevmode \@tempdima \cftf... ￼l.2 ...h wall and floor panel layouts.\relax }}{7}
```

So yeah.. not sure how helpful that is. I'm like 99% sure it's due to some sort of formatting specification I made for sections or my table of contents or something, I just have no idea which one and the errors aren't the most helpful thing. So if you have specific questions that might help you diagnose the issue I'm glad to answer them.

Comment: It seems, IMHO, that you have a problem with a `figure`. To precise the problem, have you tried running the code with only `\listoftables` ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Eisen - yes, if I run the code with only tables or figures I still get errors. Although that makes a lot of sense that the error is with figures / tables... I will look into those.

Comment: @EisenHeim I had some figures and tables that were improperly referenced, but now I'm sure every figure and table is referenced correctly and there are no duplicate names. I will try removing various formatting rules I've made and see if that helps, but any advisement would be appreciated.

Comment: As Martin said, post a running example with figures, with your preamble, it will allow us to run it and see where it fails.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: A friend tried to help out, he made a MWE that still had the error, then solved the error, but then when we put it back in my original code the error was still there. I ended up just making a manual list of figures and tables.

Comment: @Conor: I am pretty sure that posting the MWE **here** would have been much more helpful instead of manually generating the LoF and LoT -- I've voted to close